# PIL filter pixels and paste

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to paste an image onto another one. I am actually using the second answer by Joseph [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311817/overlaying-just-black-pixels-from-an-image-over-another-using-python-imaging-lib) because I am trying to do something very similar: resize my foregroud to the background image, and then copy only the black pixels in the foreground onto the background. My foreground is a color image with black contours, and I want only the contours to be pasted on the background. The line

```
mask = pixel_filter(mask, (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 0, 0))
```

returns the error "image index out of range".

When I don't do this filtering process to see if pasting at least works, I get a "bad mask transparency error". I have set the background and foreground to RGB and RGBA both to see if any combination solves the problem, it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong in the mask() line, and what am I missing about the paste process? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pixel filter` function you are referencing has a slight bug it seems. It's trying to convert a 1 dimensional list index into a 2d index backwards. It should be `(x,y)` => `(index/height, index%height)` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494974/convert-1d-array-index-to-2d-array-index)). Below is the function ([full attribution to the original author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311817/overlaying-just-black-pixels-from-an-image-over-another-using-python-imaging-lib)) rewritten.

```
def pixel_filter(image, condition, true_colour, false_colour):
    filtered = Image.new("RGBA", image.size)
    pixels = list(image.getdata())
    for index, colour in enumerate(pixels):
        if colour == condition:
            filtered.putpixel((index/image.size[1],index%image.size[1]), true_colour)
        else:
            filtered.putpixel((index/image.size[1],index%image.size[1]), false_colour)
    return filtered
```