# Overlaying coloured pixels on top of an image using Python Imaging Library

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

Okay, first thing first. This is a near duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311817/overlaying-just-black-pixels-from-an-image-over-another-using-python-imaging-lib).

However, the issue I am facing is slightly different in a critical way.

In my application, I read a generic file name in, load said image, and display it. Where it gets tricky is I have overlay the appearance of being 'highlighted'. To do this, I was using the `Image.blend()` function, and blending it with a straight yellow image.

However, when dealing with blend, I was fighting the error that the two images are not compatible to be blended. To solve this, I opened the sample image I had in paint, and just pasted yellow over the whole thing, and saved it as a copy.

It just occurred to me that this will fail when a different type of image is read in by file name. Remember this needs to be generic.

So my question is: Instead of making a copy of the image manually, can I get python to generate one by copying the image and modifying it so it is solid yellow? Note: I do not need to save it after, so just making it happen is enough.

Unfortunately, I am not allowed to share my code, but hopefully the following will give an idea of what I need:

```
from PIL import Image 

desiredWidth = 800
desiredHeight = 600

primaryImage = Image.open("first.jpg").resize((desiredWidth, desiredHeight), Image.ANTIALIAS)

# This is the thing I need fixed:
highlightImage = Image.open("highlight.jpg").resize((desiredWidth, desiredHeight), Image.ANTIALIAS)

toDisplay = Image.blend(primaryImage, highlightImage, 0.3)
```

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: `yellow = (255,255,0); Image.new(primaryImage.mode,primaryImage.size,yellow)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to make a [`new`](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.0/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.new) image:

```
fill_color = (255,255,0) #define the colour as (R,G,B) tuple

highlightImage = Image.new(primaryImage.mode, #same mode as the primary
                           primaryImage.size, #same size as the primary
                           fill_color)#and the colour defined above
```

this creates a [new](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.0/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.new) image with the same mode and size as the already opened image, but with a solid colour. Cheers.

Also if you are using Pillow instead of original PIL you can even get the color by name:

```
from PIL.ImageColor import getcolor

overlay = 'yellow'
fill_color = getcolor(overlay, primaryImage.mode)
```